# Column with exact date and time of recording

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

How to Add to a Database Table the Exact Date and Time, Adding a New Record to this Table

```
SELECT * FROM test;

ID         NAME       DT
---------- ---------- ----------
1         Ana         01.01.2019  00:00:00
2         Ina         01.01.2019  00:00:00
```

I want the exact time when this one was created
example:

```
ID         NAME       DT
---------- ---------- ----------
1         Ana         01.01.2019  10:41:22
2         Ina         01.01.2019  10:45:17



CREATE TABLE table
(
Id  NUMBER(10),
Name varcahar2(10),
DT   date
);
```

Comment: The table itself is OK; question is what value you're inserting into the DT column (should be SYSDATE) and the way you're displaying it (one option is to use `TO_CHAR(dt, 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')`) if - by default - you don't see time component.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
Id  NUMBER(10),
Name varchar2(10),
DT   date
);
```

Insert data:

```
INSERT INTO test values (1, 'Ana', sysdate);
INSERT INTO test values (2, 'Ina', sysdate);
COMMIT;
```

Query results:

```
SELECT id, name, TO_CHAR(dt, 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') FROM test;
    ID NAME       TO_CHAR(DT,'DD.MM.Y
---------- ---------- -------------------
         1 Ana        02.09.2019 10:07:18
         2 Ina        02.09.2019 10:07:18
```

Answer (score 1):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name(
  Id   NUMBER(10),
  Name VARCHAR2(10),
  DT   DATE
);
```

**Option 1**:

Use a `DATE` and `INTERVAL` literals:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name ( id, name, dt )
VALUES ( 1, 'Ana', DATE '2019-01-01' + INTERVAL '10:41:22' HOUR TO SECOND );
```

**Option 2**:

Use `TO_DATE` and convert from a string:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name ( id, name, dt )
VALUES ( 2, 'Ina', TO_DATE( '2019-01-01 10:45:17', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) );
```

**Option 3**:

Use a `TIMESTAMP` literal:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name ( id, name, dt )
VALUES ( 3, 'Ona', TIMESTAMP '2019-01-01 10:49:12' );
```

**Option 4**:

If you want the current date & time then use `SYSDATE`:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name ( id, name, dt )
VALUES ( 4, 'Una', SYSDATE );
```

or `CURRENT_DATE`:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name ( id, name, dt )
VALUES ( 4, 'Una', CURRENT_DATE );
```

**Output**:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
SELECT * FROM table_name;
```

or

```sql
SELECT id, name, TO_CHAR( dt, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) AS dt FROM table_name;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> ID | NAME | DT                 
> -: | :--- | :------------------
>  1 | Ana  | 2019-01-01 10:41:22
>  2 | Ina  | 2019-01-01 10:45:17
>  3 | Ona  | 2019-01-01 10:49:12
>  4 | Una  | 2019-09-02 09:22:28
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=090f22ac9f1cbe4ba974d50f8aa73168)*

Answer (score 0):

use TIMESTAMP

```
CREATE TABLE table
(
Id  NUMBER(10),
Name varchar2(10),
DT   TIMESTAMP
);
```

Comment: As far as Oracle is concerned, DATE will do the job as the OP wants information up to seconds.

Comment: I tried time stamp but the answer was "03-SEP-19 12.00.00.000000 AM"

Answer (score 0):

Insert current date with your data, and use analytical function to compare time since last event.

```
    CREATE TABLE so_test
    (
    Id  NUMBER(10),
    Name varchar2(10),
    DT   date
    );
    insert into so_test values (1, 'Scott', sysdate);
    insert into so_test values (2, 'Andrii', sysdate);
    insert into so_test values (3, 'Zaynul', sysdate);

    select id, name, dt 
      ,round((dt-LAG(dt) OVER (ORDER BY id))*86400) seconds_diff
    from so_test

        ID NAME       DT                  SECONDS_DIFF
---------- ---------- ------------------- ------------
         1 Scott      02-09-2019 16:02:47             
         2 Andrii     02-09-2019 16:02:58           11
         3 Zaynul     02-09-2019 16:03:12           14
```